# GIT: merge branch1 and branch2 into master without overwriting

Tags: git

I have the following scenario:

1. Created new branch `branch1` from `master`
2. In `branch1`, I added a new file called `b1.txt` + also in `common.txt` I added new line `echo 'line added in branch1';`.
3. Created new branch `branch2` from `branch1`
4. Renamed the file `b1.txt` to `b2.txt` + also in `common.txt` I changed that line to `echo 'line added in branch2';`.
5. Merged `branch1` into `master`
6. Merged `branch2` into `master`

**Result**: `master` has 1 new file `b2.txt`, and new line in `common.txt` that reads `echo 'line added in branch2';`.

**What I'd like to get as result:** `master` has 2 new files `b1.txt` and `b2.txt`, and 2 new lines in `common.txt` that reads `echo 'line added in branch1';` and `echo 'line added in branch2';`.

**How to achieve this?**

**Note:** I know, normally, I should create `branch2` from `master`, but It's much easier to copy-paste (and slightly modify) the changes of `branch1`, although `branch1` is not yet merged into `master`.

Comment: You don't get this, because each branch only has one file, and the second branch effectively deleted the first file and added a new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create `branch2` from `branch1` to use the changed files and then make `branch2` point to `master` with `git reset`:

```
git checkout master
git checkout -b branch1
* make changes and commit *
git checkout -b branch2
git reset --soft master
* make changes and commit *
```

At this point, both branches have their own changes and separate histories (up until `master`) making it easy to merge into master with `git merge branch1 branch2`.

Comment: For a moment I thought there is no alternative solution! This works perfectly!

Comment: if you have more commits in your branch2 and want to preserve them you can `git rebase -i master` from branch2 and squash relevant commits which are in branch1 and whose result is changed in branch2 into the corresponding modification commit in branch2

Answer (score 1):

In your case: Don't change, but add.

So in branch2, copy instead of rename b1.txt.
And add the line to common.txt.

You won't need to merge branch1 then, only branch2. But you could of course with no adverse affects, e.g. there are more changes in branch1.

Comment: In this case `branch2` will still have the changes of `branch1`, I don't want that, because I might drop the changes of `branch1` and push only `branch2` to `master`

Comment: That you can do of course, by removing the unwanted parts after the original branch2 changes. You can envision the whole of git like a tree, everything based on something holds it's history (i.e. changes). If you need more seperation you shouldn't branch off branch1 but instead master and copy the files on the filesystem instead ot through git.

Answer (score 1):

The commits in branch1 are also present in branch2, thus the merge of the two branches results in branch2 itself, which includes branch1.

The reason is that in the history of the modification that led to the branch2 you have all the changes in branch1, i.e. the working tree is defined by these modifications:

- (commit 1, from branch 1) start from master, create file `b1.txt`, and write `"line added in branch1"` in `common.txt`
- (commit 2, from branch 2) start from branch1, remove `b1.txt`, create `b2.txt`, and change `"branch1"` with `"branch2"` in `common.txt`

you need to rewrite the history of branch2, such that the two commits are merged into a single one with the following changeset:

- (merged commit) start from master, create file `b2.txt`, and write `"line added in branch2"` in `common.txt`

To obtain this you have to **rebase** `branch2` and **squash** commits. Refer to manual page for git-rebase to learn how to do that. Or if branch2 only has one commit in it you can just re-commit the current working tree starting from `master` instead of `branch1`. This is done, from `branch2` with clean working tree and index, with:

- `git reset --soft master`
- `git commit`

Then you can merge both branch 1 and branch 2 into master (or into each other) and get the result that you want

Answer (score 0):

How about marge `branch2` into `branch1` and then to `master`?

- git checkout a (you will switch to branch)
- git merge b (this will merge all changes from branch b into branch a)
- git commit -a (thiswill commit your changes)
- git checkout master (you will switch to branch b)
- git merge a (this will merge all changes from branch a into master)